# Step in Derivation of Multivariable Taylor Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

My question regards Muphrid's answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221669/derivation-of-multivariable-taylor-series/3127907) post.

He explains how

$$\Phi'(0)=\textbf{a}\nabla\phi(r_0),$$

but I get lost when he claims that the result holds "similarly for higher derivatives". I do not know *how* the result extends to higher derivatives of $\Phi$ nor *why* it extends in such a way.

Lastly, what is the meaning of

$$[\textbf{a}\nabla][\textbf{a}\nabla]\phi(r_0)\text{?}$$

Comment: I am not sure either exactly what "similarly for higher derivatives" means. I found Lee's explanation and calculation of the multi-variable Taylor expansion in his book [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://www.amazon.com.mx/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-John-Lee/dp/1441999817/ref=asc_df_1441999817/?tag=gledskshopmx-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=295448183641&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14933757703035865504&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1010043&hvtargid=pla-432374289780&psc=1) to be very clear.

Comment: For another thorough, and more general treatment (but I found it difficult) you might see [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/taylor.pdf).